# Unable to display header title of a website in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am unable to display the title on my website created in vuetify. I have mentioned

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: () => import('./../src/views/dashboard/Dashboard.vue'),
            meta: {
                auth: true,
                title: 'Dashboard'
            }
        },
```

in my router.js, but still title isn't displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it could help: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/914
They are suggesting some type of hook.

The second solution is a bit lower, through using a 'watcher': 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/914#issuecomment-376719306